Spark dropDuplicates() isn't dropping all duplicates
I'm reading large set of CSV files (*.csv) where the first column "colA" of the records has duplicates which I want to get rid of. That column is going to be the designated primary key for a downstream database.
Judging by the count before and after the deduplication it looks like the duplicate records are dropped.
Dataset<Row> dfDedup  = df.dropDuplicates("colA");

However at some point something happens in the workers (connection dropped) and the task is retried despite parts of the batches were written:
        dfDedup.write()
                .format("jdbc")
                ....


A bit more context - this seems to be by design. Spark is restarting stages of succeeded transactions. IMHO this makes writes with JDBC useless (except I'm missing something) as one needs to implement the database operations for each partition to reassbleme an upsert or insert or ignore.
